# Unescaping URL Parameter w/ Web.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, web.py

Reading an url as follows:

example.com/product/xy&z

```
urls = ('/product/(.*)', product)
```

In the product class on GET I am reading the that product ID pulled (xy&z) from the URL to create a DB query. Some of those IDs have an '&' in them, when I receive that value in python it has been escaped. I have had zero luck unescaping it back so I can run the query correctly. The following do not work:

```
product = product.replace("&amp;", "&")
product = HTMLParser.unescape.__func__(HTMLParser,product)
```

Whats the best practice in Web.py or even Python? Whats the best way to even diagnose this on my own? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just: `import HTMLParser; HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape( product )`?

Comment: This is working for me...  
def main():  
    product = "www.site.com/xx&amp;y"  
    print product  
    product = product.replace("&amp;", "&")  
    print product  
main()

Comment: I am guessing but pretty sure its how web.py is handling that value. I Can make a string and use replace no problem. The problem is reading this variable through web.py its handling this value differently and none of the typical options would work. Not sure how to diagnoses through web.py either.

Comment: What is the product = HTMLParser.unescape.__func__(HTMLParser,product) line for?

Comment: Nothing, sry that was a typo I took it out and replaced it with bernie's example. No luck.

Comment: I get the impression that the issue is in how web.py is storing the variable, which prevents me from using replace on it or HTMLParser.unescape. I just lack enough knowledge on how to track down the reason why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting these product ids out of box, see the following code.

```
import web

urls = (
    "/product/(.*)", "Product"
)


class Product:
    def GET(self, product_id):
        return product_id


app = web.application(urls, globals())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #app.run()
    assert web.__version__ == "0.37"
    b = app.browser()
    b.open('/product/xy&amp;z')
    assert b.status == 200
    assert "xy&amp;z" in b.data
    assert "xy&z" not in b.data
    b.open('/product/xy&z')
    assert "xy&z" in b.data
```

Please provide failing url that doesn't return desired product id.

Comment: Thanks for getting my in the right direction. I had skipped over a piece of my code assuming the issue was before the sql query but it was not. The problem I had was in creating the dictionary to be used in the query. In the declaration of the dictionary I called the product_id use web.websafe which was escaping it. Ugh, thanks so much for putting me on the right track, need to catch that myself next time.

Comment: You're welcome! Here is more information on testing web.py apps: http://webpy.org/cookbook/browser_test , but sometimes you may just drop in `print` and it will output to console when running web.py app from integrated web server

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the added information. Sometimes the webpy docs are so disorganized its hard to find the right bit of information.